# What does it mean "polyester doesn't breathe"?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, polymers, plastics

Often people say buy a cotton shirt because cotton "breathes" but polyester doesn't. (i.e. it makes you hot sweaty).

What is the scientific meaning behind this? How does polyester trap the heat more than cotton?

I would have thought it would be the other way round. Is there some chemical explanation?

Comment: That is not a scientific term. It is about permeability and thermal insulation combined. It might depend on several things. One could even be how tight is the textile but the main should be hydrophobic/hydrophilic behaviour. Advanced textiles might be also structured. Sweating does not necessarily mean polyester is "warmer", but that water cannot escape/evaporate through. Or less than with cotton. Cotton also comes with different wettability, by the way. Not sure if on chemical base or for how the fibers are worked out.

Comment: Fabric "breathing" is as Alchimista states "permeability and thermal insulation combined". Polyester is worse than cotton at allowing sweat to evaporate and pass through it, so it makes you feel hotter because the sweat is still on your skin.

Comment: I'm wondering why water can't escape, if the clothing is full of microscopic holes? Does cotton have more holes microscopically? I guess polyester fabric is more "solid"

Comment: As stated earlier this is not a scientific term, but I'd say the key is the rate at which water is transferred from one side of the fabric to the other. Because water is absorbed better by cotton, it can soak through to the outside and evaporate more quickly. Permeation of water via "microscopic holes" is likely slow compared to this process. Also the heat of evaporation of water is large and likely dominates heat transfer via conduction through the fabric. I'll admit these are kind of hand waving arguments based on observation and experience, and thus are given as a comment, not an answer.